# got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

I want to setup two coroutines, coroutine A will puts data to the queue and coroutine B will gets and prints data from the queue, if the queue is empty, coroutine B will waits until coroutine A puts some data, Why this code doesn't work as expected

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio.queues import LifoQueue

q = LifoQueue()


async def get():
    while True:
        n = await q.get()
        print(f"get {n}")
        yield n
        print(f"yield {n}")


async def put(n):
    print(f"put {n}")
    await q.put(n)


async def listen():
    async for i in get():
        print(i)


async def write():
    await put(0)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await put(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await put(2)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await put(3)


asyncio.run(asyncio.wait([listen(), write()]))
```

the output is

```py
put 0
get 0
0
yield 0
put 1
put 2
put 3
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<listen() done, defined at F:\Py\q.py:20> exception=RuntimeError("Task <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<listen() running at F:\\Py\\q.py:21> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at D:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\asyncio\\tasks.py:513]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Py\q.py", line 21, in listen
    async for i in get():
  File "F:\Py\q.py", line 9, in get
    n = await q.get()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 166, in get
    await getter
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<listen() running at F:\Py\q.py:21> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:513]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

I write a synchronous version with two threads, and it is working

```py
import time
from queue import LifoQueue
import threading

q = LifoQueue()


def get():
    while True:
        n = q.get()
        print(f"get {n}")
        yield n
        print(f"yield {n}")


def put(n):
    print(f"put {n}")
    q.put(n)


def listen():
    for i in get():
        print(i)


def puts():
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(i)
        put(i)


def main():
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=puts)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=listen)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()


main()
```

the output is

```py
put 0
get 0
0
yield 0
put 1
get 1
1
yield 1
put 2
get 2
2
yield 2
```

how to fix the former code?

Comment: I' ve run your code in Python 3.10 (not anaconda) under Windows, and it works correctly - up to printing "yield 3"  - and then it hangs (waiting for more values that will never come). Check your runtimes and how you are getting this code to run.

Comment: @jsbueno yes, in 3.10 it works, but not in previous versions, maybe event loop is changed in 3.10